# Raspberry Pi Camera V2 failure

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, pi-zero

I recently acquired a new Raspberry Pi camera module v2 to use with a Raspberry Pi Zero 1.3 and the 'official' Pi Zero case (comes with a 1.5" camera cable). 
I am running Raspbian Jessie Lite.

I have a good bit of familiarity with the Raspberry Pi platform and Linux in general (I just setup a 5x Pi 3 cluster for pyspark w/jupyter notebook in docker images, and I'm working on a Pi 3 + 4x Pi Zero cluster for mpich), so I thought this wouldn't be too difficult to setup.

Once I had everything plugged in, the Pi Zero with HDMI, a USB OTG connector + USB hub + WiFi adapter + keyboard/mouse adapter, power cable, and the camera ribbon cable, I ran:

```
raspistill -k
```

...and the output was a bunch of white and black vertical bars of varying thickness, and the output seemed to adjust if I waved my hand in front of the camera.

Is this defective hardware? What steps can I take to fix this if it is software related?

Here's an example of the image I took using the `-o` flag:

[image: A bad raspicam image]

Comment: Did you run it with the `-k` or `-o` flag?

Comment: I ran the command both with the -k and -o flag, receiving identical output. A few days ago I had the chance to head back over to microcenter and get a replacement camera, and now everything works as it should. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a not too dissimilar output when I was opening images and the dimensions were wrong, I used a V2 camera with some python bits set up for the V1 but there was an issue with ratios.

Could it be you have a version of raspistill which is using the V1 image size? The image size you've posted is 1902x1429 which i'm not spotting as a standard size.